# How to upload many images in php

Tags: php, nginx

i use php upload many images, but when i browse select images i can get only 20 images.i wanna get more images than this maybe 50 images. I go php.ini and change

```
-post_max_size = 800M
-upload_max_filesize = 800M
```

but i can't fixed problem.i still get only 20 images. How can i do? please help me

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max_file_uploads=100
```

or your desired maximum limit in php.ini

Change to your desired number and restart apache/nginx/other server.

Comment: Change it to 50/100/200 and restart apache.

Comment: yes, now i change to 50 and restart nginx, but still get only 20 images

Comment: You need to restart php5-fpm, not nginx